# Error handing in RxJava at the boundary between reactive and imperative code

Tags: java, error-handling, rx-java, rx-java2, reactive

Given an interface:

```
public interface FastlyRxApi {

    @GET("/service/{service_id}/version/{version}/backend")
    Observable<List<Backend>> listBackends(@Path("service_id") String serviceId, @Path("version") String versionId);

    @PUT("/service/{service_id}/version/{version}/backend/{old_name}")
    Observable<Backend> updateBackend(@Path("service_id") String serviceId, @Path("version") String version, @Path("old_name") String oldName, @Body Backend updatedBacked);

}
```

and some client code:

```
Integer expectedFirstByteTimeout = 10000; 

// Use a final array to capture any problem found within our composed Observables
final FastlyEnvException[] t = new FastlyEnvException[1];

fastlyRxApi.listBackends(serviceId, newVersion)
    .flatMap(Observable::fromIterable)
    .filter(backend -> !expectedFirstByteTimeout.equals(backend.getFirstByteTimeout()))
    .flatMap(backend -> {
        backend.setFirstByteTimeout(expectedFirstByteTimeout);
        return fastlyRxApi.updateBackend(serviceId, newVersion, backend.getName(), backend);
    }).subscribe(ignore -> {
}, e -> {
    t[0] = new FastlyEnvException("failed to configure backends", e);
});

if (t[0] != null) {
    throw t[0];
}
```

Using a final array of `FastlyEnvException` to capture context for error handling feels like I'm doing something wrong, and missing some aspect.

Am I using a hammer rather than a screwdriver here; ie should I be using RxJava for this? It seems to give me a nice readable flow, apart from the error handling. What is the preferred idiom for doing this?

Comment: preferred way of handling errors in rxjava is onError block in a subscription

Comment: Isn't that what I have above? The `onError` block is storing an exception in the array. But it feels clunky.

Comment: not exactly. failures in reactive programming are just another type of notifications, so the stream can either complete or emit an error. so in your case you shouldn't throw any exceptions to handle them later, you need to handle them where they are occurred, ie your subscription. also read `resilient` part of reactive systems in reactive manifesto to better understand what I mean.

Answer (score 1):

Use `onErrorResumeNext`:

```
.onErrorResumeNext(err -> 
     Observable.error(new FastlyEnvException("failed to configure backends", e)))
.toBlocking();
.subscribe();
```

Of note here is the `.toBlocking()`, this will make the Observable chain wait until it's complete.

Given that the subscribe() doesn't have an error handler, it will re-throw the exception.

Comment: RxJava2, so that would be `blockingSubscribe()`?

Comment: Correct. The point is to wait for the operation to complete, otherwise you can end up exiting the method while you're still fetching data.

Answer (score 0):

Just omit error handler in your `subscribe()` and the error will be rethrown automatically.

Comment: note: `OnErrorNotImplementedException` will be thrown but you can get your original exception via `getCause()` method.